# SVN ignore build.xml file not working

Tags: svn

We are using subversion for our java webapplication, with 3 branches QA, Staging & Live.
i want to commit build.xml into a branch but want to ignore it from svn update command as the developer will have his own IDE generated build.xml. 
How can i do that graphically or using svn commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is tracked by SVN will be updated when you do an SVN Update, unless you do not include it in the update command. That would mean not including the file or the folder of the file while doing the update.

Comment: we hardly use svn commands for svn update, max of update is done directly from IDE. Can we ignore the file and commit?

Comment: @SangramAnand - You either ignore or you commit. There is no AND.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mark file to be ignored on update - it can be ignored only on commit.

I would highly recommend creating another file - `build.xml.tmpl`. I recommend to commit it into the repository and completely ignore changes of `build.xml` by marking it as ignored (using `svn:ignore` property).

This approach will help you to avoid frequent changes of `build.xml` by other developers which you do not want to see. I guess that's the reason why you do not want to have updates of specific file.

Moreover, having template file will help to divide responsibility over build.xml file. It would have general build workflow (not to be changed by anybody, only by build manager) described in `build.xml.tmpl` and customizable `build.xml` to be freely changed in local working copy by any developer in order to adapt general workflow for specific environment/usage/properties.